# How to get only one row from a related model in laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I am using Laravel 5.1. In short, I have an entity Post that could have many versions: several draft versions and one published version. "Published" is a property of a post version. So, I have two models, one controller and a view:

Post Model:

```
class Post extends Model{

  public function published(){
     return $this->hasMany('App\PostVersion')->where('published', 1);
  }
}
```

PostVersion Model:

```
class PostVersion extends Model{

  public function post(){
     return $this->belogsTo('App\Post');
  }
}
```

And here is my controller:

```
class PostsController extends Controller{

  public function index(){

      // Only published version of all posts
      $posts = Post::with('published')->get();
      return view('posts.index', compact('posts'));       
  }
}
```

I have only one version post published. So, when $posts are iterated, I would like to to do something like this:

```
$post->published->title
```

instead of

```
$post->published[0]->title
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define **published** relation as One-to-One, not One-to-Many:

```
class Post extends Model {
  public function published(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\PostVersion')->where('published', 1);
  }
}
```